# Работа с датами в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Проблемы с изучением руби, задание считать с csv файла даты(дд.мм.гг), и после, вывести даты (все даты 21 века) которые наступают раньше и, отдельно, которые наступают позже введенной даты. Пока что смог реализовать только считывание(и то по моему криво) и вывод. Застрял на попытках отсортировать их.(в файле 3 даты
12.05.2021
21.01.2016
23.12.2019) файл http://rghost.ru/88rySyvnc

```
require 'CSV'
require 'date'
require 'twitter_cldr' 
class Date
  sort_date = gets
  sort_date1 = sort_date.split('<br>').map(&:strip).map { |d| DateTime.parse(d) }
file = File.new("date.csv")
file.each do |line|
  line.split('.').last.to_i
  date = line.split('<br>').map(&:strip).map { |d| DateTime.parse(d) }
  date1 = date
  puts "#{date1}"
end
end
```

Comment: `class Date` <- эм-м, зачем?

Comment: Приведите сам CSV-файлик, кстати. Будет гораздо проще объяснять суть ошибок, видя исходные данные и зная результат.

Comment: Класс на всякий создал. В принципе можно и без него

Comment: уже поправил. два end не скопировал просто)))

Comment: @user206618 У вас на самом деле и блок file.each do |line| не закрыт. Класс вам ведь не обязателен?

Comment: еще один для цикла

Comment: в принципе нет. если rubocop конечно ругаться не будет.

Comment: @user206618, а почему используется <br>, а не перевод строки? Есть какой-то умысел?

Comment: И зачем тут переоткрывается `class Date`, всё ещё загадка. Изменения в него никакие не вносятся.

Comment: Мой код считывает с файла и преобразовывает в формат даты, но как сравнить и отсортировать я так понять и не смог. Документацию на Data и DataTime прочитал

Comment: @cheops умысла никакого нет)

Comment: ((2459347j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] как можно избавиться от таких окончаний в выводе?)

Comment: @D-side класс в принципе пока что не нужен. просто остался от старых попыток

Comment: Кажется понял, попробую сделать через Time

Answer (score 1):

Одноколоночный CSV можно обрабатывать, считая значением **всю строку**, поэтому, при наличии такого файла:

```
12.05.2021
21.01.2016
23.12.2019
```

Можно:

```
sorted_dates = File.readlines('dates.csv')             # Получили массив строк из файла
                   .map { |x| Date.parse(x) }          # Преобразовали каждую строку в дату
                   .sort                               # ...
                   .map { |d| d.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') } # Обратно в строки с форматом
```

Поскольку вы хотите проделать с датами какие-то манипуляции, последний `.map` вы захотите отложить до момента, когда захотите сделать вывод результата. У дат (`Date`) есть свой отличный оператор сравнения и масса других полезных методов.

Массив можно отфильтровать/перевернуть/преобразовать [всем арсеналом `Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Не нужно определять класс `Date`. Такой класс есть в стандартной библиотеке. Если нужен класс для реализации основной логики (это нормальный подход), то стоит назвать его по-другому и более семантично.
2. Не нужно объявлять класс только чтобы в теле выполнять какой-то алгоритм.
3. В стандартной библиотеке есть класс для работы с `CSV`. Если по задаче требуется работать с файлом как с CSV - имеет смысл использовать его.
4. Если я правильно понял, сортировать даты не нужно.

[Вот пример класса](http://pastie.org/10780283)

Использование:

```
parser = CsvDateParser.new("/path/to/file/date.csv")
p 'greater'
parser
  .greater_than(Date.parse("2017-01-01"))
  .each { |element| puts element }
```

Выведет на экран

> "greater"
>
> 2021-05-12
>
> 2019-12-23

```
p "less"
parser
  .less_than(Date.parse("2017-01-01"))
  .each { |element| puts element }
```

Выведет на экран

> "less"
>
> 2016-01-21

```
p "all"
parser
  .all
  .each { |element| puts element }
```

=>

> "all"
>
> 2021-05-12
>
> 2016-01-21
>
> 2019-12-23

Answer (score 0):

Отсортировать даты в приведенном вами формате (DD.MM.YYYY) можно следующим образом

```
require 'CSV'

date = '21.01.2016'
day, month, year = date.split '.'

dates = CSV.read('date.csv').collect{|x| x[0]}.sort do |x, y|
  xday, xmonth, xyear = x.split '.'
  yday, ymonth, yyear = y.split '.'
  "#{yyear}.#{ymonth}.#{yday}" <=> "#{xyear}.#{xmonth}.#{xday}"
end.reject do |date|
  xday, xmonth, xyear = date.split '.'
  "#{year}.#{month}.#{day}" < "#{xyear}.#{xmonth}.#{xday}"
end
p dates
```

Comment: Не сортирует же?

Comment: @user206618, у вас результат такой? ["12.05.2021", "23.12.2019", "21.01.2016"], если вам нужно отсортировать обратном порядке, поменяйте строки в операторе <=> местами. Сортировка идет по году, потом по месяцу, потом по дню.

Comment: упс. да. не заметил, что сортирует, но не в том порядке)))

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: а как можно организовать сравнение с введенной?

Comment: точнее как преобразовать введенную в такой же вид

Comment: Разбейте её по аналогии на дату, месяц и год sort_date.split '.'. Возьмите итератор reject и отбросьте им из массива все даты, которые меньше заданной.

Comment: спасибо попробую)

Comment: а как с переменной в reject сравнить?

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: аааа. понял. спасибо

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, по месяцам не сортирует. т.е. выводит только те даты, у которых год строго меньше. на месяц и тем более день внимание не обращается)

Comment: Если в датах имеется ведущий ноль у месяца и дня - такого быть не должно. Если они отсутствуют, лучше преобразовать строки в полноценные объекты Date и сравнить их.